# Unable to upgrade openSUSE Leap 42.2 to 42.3

Tags: boot, opensuse, upgrade, zypper, dracut

I'm trying to upgrade from openSUSE Leap 42.2 to 42.3 using:

```
:~> cd /etc/zypp/repos.d

:~> sed -i 's/42.2/42.3/' *

:~> zypper refresh

:~> zypper dup

:~> reboot
```

After rebooting I get messages such as:

```
BERT: Can't request iomem region<……………>
Spectre V2: System may be vulnerable to spectre V2
dracut initqueue [282] Warning: /dev/mapper/isw_cfiadgibeh_Mirror1_part1 does not exist.
Starting Dracut emergency shell.......
Generating "/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt"
Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
Type "journalctl" to view system logs.
Recovery of btrfs system is not automated
dracut:/#
```

This is all new to me and I don't know what's going on. Can anyone put me in the picture and suggest how to put things right? All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've run into this before doing an openSUSE upgrade. If possible I'd recommend downloading the 42.3 ISO, burn it to USB, and boot into it and do the upgrade from there. Every time I've run into an issue like you're seeing, upgrading from a bootable USB always fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you finish the upgrade successfully?

It would be interesting to know which repos you have/had in /etc/zypp/repos.d/.

I would recommend to disable repos from third parties and only enable these 4 repos for the upgrade, and afterwards manage your third party repos and packages:

- http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/oss/
- http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/15.0/repo/non-oss/
- http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.0/oss/
- http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/15.0/non-oss/

Anyway, I think the failing boot is based on this message:

> /dev/mapper/isw_cfiadgibeh_Mirror1_part1 does not exist

You should check /etc/fstab or autofs for configuration issues, maybe comment out entries that cause trouble and fix it after the system boots successfully.